# Database Project In VS2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I have  VS2005 Team suit installed and also VS2005 Team edition for DB Proff. Now I took down a solution with three db projects in it but they din't load. I tried reload but it failed as well with error that SQL SERVER WAS NOT FOUND OR NOT ACCESSIBLE....ERROR 26.

I went in tools - options - dbtools - design time validation db and checked the server instance name and connect to it thru sql server 2005 mgmt studio and got in ok.

what could be the issue for unloaded db projects in VS ?

does it use windows authentication when connecting from VS?